# Am I going crazy or this is a bug in C#?

Tags: .net, binary-search

```
public static void Main()
{

    int[] nums = new int[] {1,0,1,2,3};     
    int k = Array.BinarySearch<int>(nums, 0);
    Console.WriteLine(k);
}
```

Why is the Binary search of 0 in the int[] array return a -1 instead of the index where 0 is at?

Comment: From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.8): Searches a one-dimensional _sorted_ Array for a value, using a binary search algorithm.

Comment: See description of the Returns here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.8 -- **"If this method is called with a non-sorted array, the return value can be incorrect and a negative number could be returned, even if value is present in array."**

Answer (score 2):

[`BinarySearch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_BinarySearch_System_Array_System_Object_) only works if the elements are in order.

> Searches an entire one-dimensional ***sorted*** array for a specific element...

You can use `IndexOf` instead, which performs a linear search:

```
int k = nums.IndexOf(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

`BinarySearch` expects the input to be sorted. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_BinarySearch__1___0_____0_):

> If this method is called with a non-sorted array, the return value can be incorrect and a negative number could be returned, even if value is present in array.